# Setting a StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have 3 buttons: "Q", "W" and "E". When clicked they should append their letter to a `StringBuilder`. Like this:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
```

(When "Q" button is clicked):

```
s.append("q");
```

(When "W" button clicked):

```
s.append("w");
```

But what I want is to have a maximum of 3 characters to be in the `StringBuilder`.
3 digits after reaching the initial character of a key is pressed at the end wiper and write a new one. After the `StringBuilder` reaches three characters, it will remove the initial one and append the next. Like marquee.
Example:

```
StringBuilder is "QWW",
When E button clicked StringBuilder must be "WWE".
When W button clicked StringBuilder must be "WEW".
```

Comment: I hate to write this... But... What have you tried?

Comment: @MarounMaroun lol..Me too.. So Erkan what have you tried...?

Comment: Adding to @MarounMaroun, do you have sample code you have written so that we can help you fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe you don't want a StringBuilder, but a circular buffer?

Comment: Yes i tried. But not working. Pls help me

Comment: Agree with @NilsH, this isn't StringBuilder, what you want is more of a character Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`StringBuilder#deleteCharAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt%28int%29):

```
public static void addToStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb, int max, char letter)
{
    if(sb.length() >= max) sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    sb.append(letter);
}
```

For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
addToStringBuilder(sb, 3, 'Q');
System.out.println(sb);
addToStringBuilder(sb, 3, 'W');
System.out.println(sb);
addToStringBuilder(sb, 3, 'W');
System.out.println(sb);
addToStringBuilder(sb, 3, 'E');
System.out.println(sb);
addToStringBuilder(sb, 3, 'W');
System.out.println(sb);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Q
QW
QWW
WWE
WEW
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way is to use char array

```
char[] arr = new char[]{'','',''};
...
private void appendChar(char a){
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
  }
  arr[arr.length-1] = a;
}
```

And finally:

```
String res = new String(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
public void prepareBuilder(String str)
{
  if (sBuilder.length() < 3)
  sBuilder.append(str);
  else 
  {
    sBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
    sBuilder.append(str);

  }
}
```